# Taylor Expansion of $f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})+1}$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, taylor-expansion, maple

> Find the Taylor series expansion of the following function around $x=0$
>
> $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})+1}$$

**My solution:**

$$f(0)=\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=0$$
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{(x^2 +x) (\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})+1)^2}=0$$
$$f''(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}f''(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2}{(\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})+1)^3x^4(1+1/x)^2}-\frac{2}{(\ln(1+1/x)+1)^2 x^3 (1+1/x)}+\frac{1}{(\ln(1+1/x)+1)^2 x^4 (1+1/x)^2}=-\infty$$

It looks like something is wrong, What should I do now?

MAPLE gives me the following. It does not work for me since the terms behind $x^{K}$ depend on $x$:

$$\frac{a}{\ln(1/x)+a}-\frac{a x}{(\ln(1/x)+a)^2}+\frac{(1/2)a/(\ln(1/x)+a)+a/(\ln(1/x)+a)^2}{\ln(1/x)+a}x^2$$

Comment: $f(0)$ is not defined. Check the function or the point where the Taylor series is at .

Comment: @DeepSea Thanks. Check them for what?

Comment: Maple 2017.1 give me the same answer what Mathematica 11.1 :`1/(1 + Log[1/x]) - x/(1 + Log[1/x])^2 + ((3 + Log[1/x]) x^2)/(
 2 (1 + Log[1/x])^3) + ((-7 - 5 Log[1/x] - Log[1/x]^2) x^3)/(
 3 (1 + Log[1/x])^4)`

Comment: I have $f(x)$ is not defined when $x\le0$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to 0^+} f'(x) = \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\ln x$ has a non-removable singularity at $x=0$, your expression would not be expected to have a valid Taylor series (or even a valid MacLauren series starting from some negative power of $x$) about $x=0$.

The Taylor series about $x=1$ starts with
$$
\frac{1}{1+\ln 2}+\frac1{2(1+\ln 2)^2}(x-1)-\frac{3\ln 2 + 1}{8(1+\ln 2)^3}(x-1)^2\cdots
$$

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you mean "Laurent series"? :)